# Dynamically add range values to excel chart with C#

Tags: c#, excel, dynamic, charts, powerpoint

I am trying to generate a chart for a powerpoint slide using C#.net. The chart works perfectly when I hard code the data, so my goal here is to be able to populate the excel backend from my applications datatable. What i need help with is defining the data ranges(see below)

```
 var areaworkbook = (EXCEL.Workbook)areachart.ChartData.Workbook;
 areaworkbook.Windows.Application.Visible = false;

 var dataSheet2 = (EXCEL.Worksheet)areaworkbook.Worksheets[1];
 var sc2 = areachart.SeriesCollection();

 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["A2"].Value2 = "Name 1";
 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["A3"].Value2 = "Name 2";
 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["A4"].Value2 = "Name 3";
 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["A5"].Value2 = "Name 4";
 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["B2"].Value2 = Value 1;
 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["B3"].Value2 = value 2;
 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["B4"].Value2 = value 3;
 dataSheet1.Cells.Range["B5"].Value2 = value 4 ;

 var series2 = sc2.NewSeries();
 series2.Name = "Series 2";
 series2.XValues = "'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$5";
 series2.Values = "'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$5";
 series2.ChartType = Office.XlChartType.xlAreaStacked;


 areachart.HasTitle = true;
 areachart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = true;
 areachart.ChartTitle.Font.Italic = true;
 areachart.ApplyLayout(4);
 areachart.Refresh();
```

How will I dynamically add A6, A7, A8... until my datatable is complete?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a loop and calculate the cell address.  For the sake of argument, I'm going to assume the data is coming from a Linq query, though you could get it any other way.

```
int row = 2; // You expect to start here
foreach (var data in db.MyData().Where(... whatever you need here ...))
{
    dataSheet1.Cells.Range["A" + row].Value2 = data.Name;
    dataSheet1.Cells.Range["B" + row].Value2 = data.Value;
    row++;
}

series2.XValues = "'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$" + row;
series2.Values = "'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$" + row;
```